# With Nokogiri i am getting error "initialize': getaddrinfo: No such host is known. (SocketError)"

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I worte the below code, just to start the Nokogiri to mee the requirement and when I ran it for testing got the error:

```
D:\WIPData\Ruby\Scripts>Nokogiri.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: No such
host is known.  (SocketError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:775:in `buffer_open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
        from D:/WIPData/Ruby/Scripts/Nokogiri.rb:6:in `<main>'

D:\WIPData\Ruby\Scripts>
```

***CODE***

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Get a Nokogiri::HTML::Document for the page we’re interested in...

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.co.in'))
```

Why so and how to fix the same,please advice me.

Comment: That's not Nokogiri; it's open-uri complaining that the hostname `www.google.co.in` doesn't exist. Do you need a proxy to get to the internet?

Comment: Yes `http://www.google.co.in/` it is for India. And it is running on my browser but not from the script.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes, we do! Anyway it is blocked by the `Firewall`! Any help how to deal with that `firewall`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you need to configure a proxy. Find out what the proxy URL/Port is for your organization (and whether there needs to be authentication). You may be able to view this information from your browser configuration. In order to use it with your Ruby code, you need to set the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable.

You can set it in Ruby code:

```
ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://hostname:port'
```

or if you need authentication:

```
ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://username:password@hostname:port'
```

A more permanent solution is to set `HTTP_PROXY` in your system environment variables.

Comment: OMG! you atleast given a `hope`. Yes I can set it. But where and how I need to set it up? Where to place it? Please please tell me. If anyway it works then my code will work. I don't need permanent, only due to code run I need the could should run peach fully and do the work as assigned to it. `Proxy-'3.209.30.25'` and `port:80`. we used it permanently in our firefox browser and IE9 both.

Comment: `+1` to you first of all,hoping it will work,as you are senior and expert on this platform,rather than me.I am just 15 days doing code on this platform. `Noekogiri`,`Mechanize` - they are itself is a browser. If I set that `ENV` then the browser of these will be benefitted. Am I right? Right now I am in home and eager to test your solution,to see that my stuck point has been overcome. :)

Comment: Put it as early as possible in the code, certainly before you open a URL. Good luck.

Comment: I'm also facing the "host unknown" issue. When I saw my system proxy settings, it is selected as "Automatically detect proxy settings". In such a case, is there any way to trigger a https request in ruby?

Comment: Sure, find out what your autodetected settings are, and put the proxy in the HTTP_PROXY environment variable. Assuming you're talking about IE on Windows, see http://superuser.com/questions/33588/how-to-view-internet-explorer-auto-detected-proxy-settings and http://lists.samba.org/archive/linux/2003-January/006039.html