# How do I know what port I am using?

Tags: ruby, port

I have a proxy that it is blocking me from using Nokogiri, Does anyone know what port is being used?

My script runs fine from home but not at work.

Comment: Most big companies use some sort of www-proxy in their firewall to prevent direct outbound connections. The HTTP default port is 80, and that is what your company firewall is probably blocking.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14463138/182590

Comment: Nokogiri has nothing to do with ports, it simply reads from an IO stream or accepts a string. Also, without any source-code it'd very difficult to help you. Your port could be set to a non-standard value and we'd have to guess from thousands of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your company's proxy settings (ask them, or look at your browser settings) then with `open-uri` you can get through the firewall like this:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, :proxy => 'http://[proxy_host]:[proxy_port]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the document from work with a browser? If not, it's a proxy issue. The port gets remapped in the proxy if it (and work) deems the URL legal.